# Hovering Over links won't show their location in the status bar

Tags: firefox

All of a sudden, firefox has stopped showing links in the status bar when i hover over them. I can confirm it was working as late as last night. I can't think of anything that would do this, but it's possible i did it i suppose. How can i get them back?

Comment: Is it possible that this is caused by an extension? Have you verified if this also happens in safe mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it cleared up jsut now for no apparent reason... :S

Answer (score 2):

Does this happens to all sites you go to, or with an specific site? It is possible to replicate such behavior with a bit of JavaScript. Does any other browser do that same?

Comment: All sites, and i don't think any other browser has a problem.